# Map Freezes on iOS 7 with Google Maps SDK 1.4

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

I've been seeing a strange issue using Google Maps SDK 1.4 (and 1.2... probably others) on iOS 7 beta 4 and 5.

After a brief time of zooming and panning on a device running iOS 7 beta 4 or 5, my GMSMapView will stop responding to gestures. It wont zoom or pan or do anything when you touch it.

When this happens, every other interface element present on screen will remain functional. Programmatically removing and adding the map from the view will re-enable the map. Rotating the device does not affect the map.
It happens only on a device running the iOS 7 beta and not on a simulator running iOS 7. Running the same app on an iOS 5.1 and 6.x device will not reproduce this issue.

Has anyone else had an issue like this? I am not a seasoned iOS developer, so I could be missing something simple.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: No problem with mine...

Comment: I'm having the same issue on the simulator

Comment: Experiencing the same issue with v1.4.3 and 7.0 GM

Comment: Can you confirm if this is still an issue with v1.5 and 7.0 GM? If yes, can you file a bug on https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/ with the source code? I need a repro case to be able to chase engineering with.

Comment: I'm still seeing this issue on iOS 7 with Google Maps 1.6.1...

Comment: Did you come to any conclusion about the reason why was this happening ? as i am facing similar issue.

Answer (score 4):

GMSMapView(UIViewController) on UINavigationController.
Insert this code in viewDidLoad method.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // iOS7   add this code  
    if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
    }

.... your codes

}
```

Comment: I no longer have this problem in my app and am not exactly sure when it seemed to fix itself, but I'm curious if this works for others, and more importantly, why it works.

Comment: This seems to have fixed the issue . +1 for that , can you please explain the reason behind this.

Comment: iOS 7 has a built in feature to allow users to navigate backwards through navigation controllers by swiping from the left edge of the screen to the right. It looks like this code disables that feature because I can only assume that the iOS' interactivePopGestureRecognizer may interfere with Google's map gesture recognizer.

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest version of Google Maps SDK. This issue has been solved in Version 1.8.0 - May 2014.

Check the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/releases).